# Case Statement - Column names in each table must be unique

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am writing sql to perform some data migration and manipulation. I am writing some somewhat complicated logic to map from the source data to our destination data. Essentially, two fields from the source will map into ONE field in the destination, but obviously certain fields take precedence. My logic looks somewhat like this:

```
case
   when d.PURPOSE_NAME = 'Downsize' and (a.DEAL_TYPE_NAME <> '30-Day Letter' and a.DEAL_TYPE_NAME <> 'ACL' and a.DEAL_TYPE_NAME <> 'Assignment') then 'Renewal'
   when d.PURPOSE_NAME = 'Early Renewal' and (a.DEAL_TYPE_NAME <> '30-Day Letter' and a.DEAL_TYPE_NAME <> 'ACL' and a.DEAL_TYPE_NAME <> 'Assignment') then 'Renewal'
   --- more
end as Deal_Type__c,
case
   when d.PURPOSE_NAME = 'Downsize' and (a.DEAL_TYPE_NAME <> '30-Day Letter' and a.DEAL_TYPE_NAME <> 'ACL' and a.DEAL_TYPE_NAME <> 'Assignment') then 'Downsize'
   when d.PURPOSE_NAME = 'Early Renewal' and (a.DEAL_TYPE_NAME <> '30-Day Letter' and a.DEAL_TYPE_NAME <> 'ACL' and a.DEAL_TYPE_NAME <> 'Assignment') then 'Early Renewal'
   --- more
end as Deal_SubType__c,

-- these values take precedence
case
   when a.DEAL_TYPE_NAME = '30-Day Letter' then 'Amendment'
   when a.DEAL_TYPE_NAME = 'ACL' then 'Amendment'
   when a.DEAL_TYPE_NAME = 'Assignment' then 'Amendment'
end as Deal_Type__c,
case
   when a.DEAL_TYPE_NAME = '30-Day Letter' then 'Option to Relet'
   when a.DEAL_TYPE_NAME = 'ACL' then 'Termination'
   when a.DEAL_TYPE_NAME = 'Assignment' then 'Assignment'
end as Deal_SubType__c,
```

This logic makes sense to me but I'm getting the error:

> Column names in each table must be unique. Column name
>   'Deal_Type__c' in table 'Opportunity' is specified more than once.

How can I use TSQL to map two fields in my source data to one field in my destination table using *case* statements?

Comment: All those cases are in your select clause?

Comment: Let me guess **`SELECT ... INTO Opportunity`** ?

Comment: @lad2025 yes exactly

Answer (score 0):

You probably use something like (simplified demo, no need for `CASE`):

```
SELECT
  1 AS Deal_Type__c,
  2 AS Deal_Type__c
INTO Opportunity;
```

> Column names in each table must be unique. Column name 'Deal_Type__c'
>   in table 'Opportunity' is specified more than once.

The problem is with your aliases, they have to be distinct.

Change aliases to distinct_names to save both values in the same row:

```
SELECT
  1 AS Deal_Type__c_1,
  2 AS Deal_Type__c_2
INTO Opportunity;
```

Use `UNION ALL` to save both values in different rows:

```
SELECT
  1 AS Deal_Type__c
INTO Opportunity
UNION ALL
SELECT
  2 AS Deal_Type__c;
```

Or take precedence(you mean not `NULL`)???

```
SELECT
   ISNULL( CASE WHEN ... END,
           CASE WHEN ... END ) AS Deal_Type__c
INTO Opportunity;
```

Like:

```
SELECT ISNULL(case
               when a.DEAL_TYPE_NAME = '30-Day Letter' then 'Amendment'
               when a.DEAL_TYPE_NAME = 'ACL' then 'Amendment'
               when a.DEAL_TYPE_NAME = 'Assignment' then 'Amendment'
              end,
              case
                when d.PURPOSE_NAME = 'Downsize' and (a.DEAL_TYPE_NAME <> '30-Day Letter' and a.DEAL_TYPE_NAME <> 'ACL' and a.DEAL_TYPE_NAME <> 'Assignment') then 'Renewal'
                when d.PURPOSE_NAME = 'Early Renewal' and (a.DEAL_TYPE_NAME <> '30-Day Letter' and a.DEAL_TYPE_NAME <> 'ACL' and a.DEAL_TYPE_NAME <> 'Assignment') then 'Renewal'
                --- more
             end) AS Deal_Type__c
    -- same for Deal_SubType__C
INTO Opportunity;
```

**EDIT:**

Using HABO's suggestion you can combine your both cases:

```
SELECT case
         when a.DEAL_TYPE_NAME = '30-Day Letter' then 'Amendment'
         when a.DEAL_TYPE_NAME = 'ACL' then 'Amendment'
         when a.DEAL_TYPE_NAME = 'Assignment' then 'Amendment'
         when d.PURPOSE_NAME = 'Downsize' and (a.DEAL_TYPE_NAME <> '30-Day Letter' and a.DEAL_TYPE_NAME <> 'ACL' and a.DEAL_TYPE_NAME <> 'Assignment') then 'Renewal'
         when d.PURPOSE_NAME = 'Early Renewal' and (a.DEAL_TYPE_NAME <> '30-Day Letter' and a.DEAL_TYPE_NAME <> 'ACL' and a.DEAL_TYPE_NAME <> 'Assignment') then 'Renewal'
         --- more
        end AS Deal_Type__c
      -- same for Deal_SubType__C
INTO Opportunity;
```

Comment: Since the cases are evaluated sequentially and the results are all static strings, not column values, there is little likelihood of a NULL creeping in. The `when` clauses can all be combined into a single `case` in precedence order.

Answer (score 0):

The error is because the first and the third case has the "`Deal_Type__c`" as column name, same as second and fourth with "`Deal_SubType__c`".

If you need two (or more) sets of data going same column you need, for example, an `UNION` statement